# can't find jenkins.xml anywere on the system

Tags: jenkins, office365, jenkins-email-ext

I have installed jenkins using java-jar jenkins.war on windows 10.

I am trying to setup SMTP for outlook which suggest to enable TLS using jenkins.xml as per below suggestion

```
For Jenkins on Windows, open jenkins.xml and modify the arguments node
-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -Dmail.smtp.startt
```

but I can't fond jenkins.xml anywhere in my system

My jenkins is at  `C:\Users\myuser\.jenkins`

Comment: Look for it in `C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jenkins.xml`

Comment: The XML file is read by the service wrapper (jenkins.exe) only. If you are launching "jenkins.war" through commandline, you have to pass the arguments yourself: `java [arguments] -jar jenkins.war`